# Pulling map in my application through Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am new to iphone app development and trying to make an application where the home of the application is the Map with one button and the map should be able to show the user's current position and place an annotation at his current position.

The annotation should be bale to take input or file from the iphone (Text, picture etc).

Please guide me from base or provide me with some tutorial which will help me to understand interface builder first.

I will really appreciate your help

Thanks,

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged objective-c instead of c and objective?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/21/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0/) is a rather handy tutorial I used to integrate MKMapView into one of my apps.

Adding markers can be quite confusing at first but if you read (and re-read) the documentation, it's a doddle.